# How to open facebook connect login window?

Tags: javascript, facebook

In the new Facebook Connect [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), you'd call `FB.login()`.

How would you achieve the same thing with the [old SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was [FB.Connect.requireSession](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.requireSession).

Didn't seem very intuitive from the documentation.